# Not able to use Stream method on Array of Object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

```
        User user =list.stream()
                .filter(user -> id.equals(user.getUsername()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    
        return user;
    }
```

**The type java.util.stream.Stream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type java.util.Arrays**

I want filter from array of objects using a username.

Comment: calling `.stream()` is for use on Collections. to stream an array, you call the utility class Arrays. ie `Arrays.stream(arrayToStream)`

Comment: Please add the declaration of `list` to your question.

Comment: This error message looks like a typical annoying Eclipse problem. Sometimes, rebuilding the workspace can help. But as you can see from the other responses, it is not helpful to post incomplete and contradicting information.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `stream()` method used for `Collections` on an `Array`. You should use `Arrays.stream(arr)` instead.

So your code should be:

```java
User user = Arrays.stream(list)
    .filter(user -> id.equals(user.getUsername()))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Does doing that produce the error message the question asks about?